# Local folder mounted as empty on Ubuntu with docker-machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, mount, docker, shared-folders

Running docker-machine on Ubuntu, mounting local folder with `docker run -v` option, folder is empty in Docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that docker-machine mounted my local `/home` to `/hosthome` by default.

Also using `-v` or `--volume` option for `docker run` has a difference to `--mount` option: local folder is automatically created if it doesn't exist.

That's why when calling `docker run -v /home/a/b/c:/xxx`, an empty folder was created at path `/home/a/b/c` inside virtual machine first, and then mounted to container at path `/xxx`.

First takeaway was to stop using `-v` option and start using `--mount` instead: `docker run --mount type=bind,source=/home/a/b/c,target=/xxx`. In this case the command will *fail fast* with error as the source path doesn't exist in virtual machine.

Second step was to remove default shared folder from the virtual machine (my driver was `virtualbox`) and replace it with proper one with matching path. Performing these operations on stopped vm:

```
docker-machine stop
vboxmanage sharedfolder remove default --name hosthome
vboxmanage sharedfolder add default --name $HOME --hostpath $HOME --automount
docker-machine start
```